# Process dialog is not stop after login and when logout

Tags: android

My Application is still show processing while I go another screen and logout this process dialog still processing did not stop it.

When I press login button in login page I used this code:

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        showProgress();
        postLoginData();

    }
});

public void postLoginData() {

    if (pin.getTextSize() == 0 || mobile.getTextSize() == 0) {

        AlertDialog.Builder altDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        altDialog.setMessage("Please Enter Complete Information!");

    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
        AgAppMenu.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("mno", mobile.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("pinno", pin.getText().toString());

        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

private void showProgress() {
    myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginScreen.this, null, "Processing please wait...", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `myProgressDialog.dismiss()` as well.
Such as control it from Handler, etc..

If you want to dismiss this dialog from another activity, better to set a `static Handler` in this activity and let another activity can use `static Handler` to `sendEmptyMessage` to close it.

Comment: if i use myProgressDialog.dismiss()
in this location 

Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AgAppMenu.class);
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("mno", mobile.getText().toString());
   bundle.putString("pinno", pin.getText().toString());
  

   i.putExtras(bundle);
   myProgressDialog.dismiss();
   startActivity(i);

processdailog not shown

Comment: because it is too fast, showProgress(); then myProgressDialog.dismiss(); , or you can use postDelayed to dismiss it after certain secs.

Comment: handler `postDelayed` with Runnable to dismiss it within certain seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void showProgress()
    {    
       m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Saving And Sending Record  ...", true);
                new Thread() { public void run() {try{sleep(5000);} catch (Exception e) { }}}.start();   
    }
```